# Pandas dataframe groupby and sort

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has 4 columns where the first two columns consist of strings (categorical variable) and the last two are numbers.

```
Type    Subtype    Price    Quantity
Car     Toyota     10       1
Car     Ford       50       2
Fruit   Banana     50       20
Fruit   Apple      20       5 
Fruit   Kiwi       30       50
Veggie  Pepper     10       20
Veggie  Mushroom   20       10
Veggie  Onion      20       3
Veggie  Beans      10       10
```

How do I make it such that the dataframe is sorted in descending order based on the aggregated sum of Price on the column Type, and have the Subtype column sorted in descending order for the Price column as well? Like this:

```
Type    Subtype    Price    Quantity
Fruit   Banana     50       20
        Kiwi       30       50
        Apple      20       5 
Car     Ford       50       2
        Toyota     10       1
Veggie  Mushroom   20       10
        Onion      20       3
        Beans      10       10  
        Pepper     10       20
```

I tried the following but it did not sort the Subtype column in descending order:

```
df = df.groupby(['Type','Subtype'])['Price', 'Quantity'].agg({'Price':sum})
i = df.index.get_level_values(0)
df = df.iloc[i.reindex
                   (df['PRICE'].groupby(level=0, 
                   group_keys=False).sum().sort_values('PRICE', ascending=False).index)[1]]
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

Edit: There are multiple items under Subtype that are the same so I would like both Type and Subtype columns grouped as well.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael Sorry, the expected output is the second dataframe in my post above.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
df_new=df.groupby(['Type','Subtype'],as_index=False).apply(\
                  lambda x:x.sort_values(by='Price',ascending=False)).reset_index(drop=True)

df_new.loc[df_new.Type.duplicated(),'Type']= ''
print(df_new)

     Type   Subtype  Price  Quantity
1     Car      Ford     50         2
0            Toyota     10         1
2   Fruit    Banana     50        20
4              Kiwi     30        50
3             Apple     20         5
6  Veggie  Mushroom     20        10
7             Onion     20         3
5            Pepper     10        20
8             Beans     10        10
```

Comment: How would I groupby Subtype as well?  I really that there are of the same Subtypes as well.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seems to be sorted on Type based on Price and not grouped on the Subtype column as well

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
df.assign(sortkey = df.groupby('Type')['Price'].transform('sum'))\
  .sort_values(['sortkey','Type','Price'], ascending=[False,True,False])\
  .set_index(['Type','Subtype'])\
  .drop('sortkey', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                 Price  Quantity
Type   Subtype                  
Fruit  Banana       50        20
       Kiwi         30        50
       Apple        20         5
Car    Ford         50         2
       Toyota       10         1
Veggie Mushroom     20        10
       Onion        20         3
       Pepper       10        20
       Beans        10        10
```

Comment: How would I groupby Subtype as well?  I really that there are of the same Subtypes as well.

Comment: Sure,  add subtypes into the sort_values method and also, remember to add a True or False to the ascending list.

Answer (score 2):

Create `sorted CategoricalIndex` by aggregated values with `sum` and then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) - in last version of pandas is possible sorting index level with columns together:

```
df = df.groupby(['Type','Subtype'])[['Price', 'Quantity']].sum()

idx = df['Price'].sum(level=0).sort_values().index

i = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index.get_level_values(0), ordered=True, categories=idx)
df.index = [i, df.index.get_level_values(1)]

df = df.sort_values(['Type','Price'], ascending=False)
print (df)
                 Price  Quantity
Type   Subtype                  
Fruit  Banana       50        20
       Kiwi         30        50
       Apple        20         5
Veggie Mushroom     20        10
       Onion        20         3
       Beans        10        10
       Pepper       10        20
Car    Ford         50         2
       Toyota       10         1
```

Comment: How would I groupby Subtype as well?  I really that there are of the same Subtypes as well.

Comment: @user112947 - so need `df = df.sort_values(['Type','Subtype','Price'], ascending=False)` ? Or `df = df.sort_values(['Type','Subtype','Price'], ascending=[False, True, False])` ?

Comment: I get a "KeyError: 'Type'" error, seems like Type is an index?

Comment: @user112947 - Maybe problem not use last version of pandas